# Lipshitz constant of bounded function on disc

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the unit disc $\{z\in\mathbf{C}:|z|<1\}$ and
>   have bounded modulus in the sense that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ in
>   the disc. Let $0<r<1$. Find a constant $C$ depending on $M$ and $r$ so
>   that for all points $z,w$ of modulus less than $r$, $$ |f(z)-f(w)|\leq
> C|z-w|. $$

I can see this has to hold because of the boundedness of the derivative on  this closed disc, but I don't know how to find an explicit bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

Use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) to get $$\vert f^\prime (z) \vert \le \frac{M}{r}$$ for $\vert f(z) \vert <r$. Hence you can chose $$C=\frac{M}{r}$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Although now I'm not sure how to finish the proof without the mean value theorem. If $z$ and $w$ are such that $|z|, |w|< r$ why is it necessarily the case that
$$
\frac{|f(z)-f(w)|}{|z-w|}\leq |f'(z_0)|.
$$

Comment: MVT doesn't work for complex-valued functions, but most of its corollaries do, by various tricks. Here you don't need any tricks because $f'$ is continuous: Write $f(z)-f(w)$ as the integral of $f'$ over the line segment from $w$ to $z$.